# How to uninstall Virtualbox on windows10?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I would like to uninstall Virtualbox from my Windows10 computer, but I can not find it in the `Programs and Features` list. I was looking for an uninstaller exe in the install directory and on the internet, but I haven't found anything.

How is it possible to remove it, and all of it's drivers?

Comment: Download the installer from the VirtualBox website, run the installer, when presented with an option to install/repair/remove the current installation select remove

Comment: There is no uninstall or repair option

Comment: Be sure your using the installer to the exact same version you have installed but, of that still doesn't work, install it again then remove it

Comment: I've tried it, but the installer freezes at the end, and it is never completed

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Submit the installation log file.  Your question in its current form cannot be answered. Manually removing an unknown amount of components of a software package cannot be described and documented since we don't know what components are actually installed on your system. Update your question.

Comment: Use CCleaner(google it). It comes with an Uninstaller Functionality. Maybe That would help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete uninstall Virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/1212182/complete-uninstall-virtualbox)

Answer (score 10):

It should be called "Oracle VM Virtualbox" under `Apps & features'.  I assume you were just looking for "VirtualBox"

Comment: Does this remove the drivers that are installed alongside VirutalBox?

Comment: @Stevoisiak It should remove it completely.

Answer (score 1):

My *Start Menu* item for Oracle folder with VirtualBox had no *Uninstall* link either.

Here's how did it in my case (VirtualBox 5.x)

1. Downloaded latest installer .exe package for 5.x [from here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_2)
2. Ran it and upgraded my older version
3. Ran the same installer again, but this time chose *Remove*

NOTE: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ExtensionPacks` still remained after uninstall so I manually deleted it. Also, as noted in comments, `C:\Users\<usename>\Appdata\Local\.virtualbox` may also remain.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1212266/1157169) details that the directory `C:\Users\<usename>\Appdata\Local\.virtualbox` can remain after uninstall as well.

Comment: @applemonkey496 Thanks. I've now added it to the note.

Answer (score 0):

[Detailed instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1258517) for removing a corrupted VirtualBox installation from Windows 7 might apply as well.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the content from your other answer here as well? Even though it's on this site, it is good practice to have the information in an answer self-contained. Thanks :)

Comment: This question should just be flagged as a duplicate instead of submitting two identical answers, which results in two questions, with the same answer.  Allowing users to upvote the same answer twice.

Comment: I caution anyone from using the solution outlined in the linked answer, it’s extremely dangerous, to manual decouple driver files.  However, the accepted answer to the duplicate, is safe enough to do.

Comment: @Hope - The instructions work perfectly fine on Windows 10.  An answer to a specific OS isn't warranted if the instructions are identical.

Comment: Bizarrely this difficulty tends to occur if 6.1.18 (say) is installed on W7 which is then upgraded to W10. Updates fail, and the installed version will not uninstall. Manual brute removal is the last recourse.